# Nested UITableView not returning any cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` which has another `UITableView` nested inside one its cells (*I know* this is bad practise, don't worry!).

The problem is that when I call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` I am getting nil back.  HOWEVER this works just fine when the `UITableView` is not nested inside another one.

Is there a way to NOT reuse a `UITableViewCell`, but instead directly instatiate it every time?

I've tried using this:

```
ContactFieldCell *cell = [[ContactFieldCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:thisCellIdentifier];
```

which doesn't return nil, but then nothing appears in my `UITableView`!

Here's the code for the "parent" UITableView:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ContactCardCell";
    ContactCardCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    NSArray *objects = [[sections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"objects"];
    CDCard *card = [objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.delegate = self;

    cell.fieldsTableView = [[CardTableViewController alloc] initWithCard:card];
    [cell.fieldsTableView.view setFrame:CGRectMake(17, 12, 256, 163)];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.fieldsTableView.view];

    return cell;
}
```

and here's the code for the "child" UITableView:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *thisCellIdentifier = @"ContactFieldCell";

    ContactFieldCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:thisCellIdentifier];

    cell.delegate = self;
    cell.field = [self.card.sortedFields objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

ContactFieldCell is a prototype cell within the storyboard.  It has the following code:

```
@interface ContactFieldCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ContactFieldCellDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CDField *field;

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *displayNameLabel;

@end
```

Comment: Can you show your whole `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`?  Are you using the same class as a datasource for both UITablieViews? Or separate classes?

Comment: Done.  Updated my question.  Thanks Ansible.  Both have separate datasources.

Comment: My next thought is the cell is returning, but just now showing anything?   What does adding this before return cell in your child UITableView? `cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];`

Comment: Yeah, the cells are there (5 yellow cells).  I think because I'm using initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault it's not initialising the custom cell correctly.  What's the syntax for initialising a new custom cell?

Comment: See my answer - it will create the cell for you. Then just override `- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier`.  Also you can look at this excellent project foe an example of using a custom cell. https://github.com/smileyborg/TableViewCellWithAutoLayout

Comment: What labels do you have on your field?  You will need to update them after setting field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UITableView`s are a very powerful element and can be used to build great apps.

The only thing to keep in mind is, the basics must be clear. Now from your code, I cannot make out whether you have assigned the `delegate`s and `dataSource`s properly, but I'll still mention it in case someone else needs it.

You have a subclassed `UITableViewCell` which in turn contains a `UITableView`. The `UIViewController` must be the `delegate` and `dataSource` for the outer `UITableView`. Make sure you have set it in both the `.h` and `.m` file.

Next, your custom cell must also be the `delegate` and `dataSource`, but for the inner `UITablewView`. I suppose here, you have created the inner `UITableView` in the `init` method of the `UITableViewCell`. Set the `delegate` and `dataSource` there itself. Then you set other runtime properties in the `drawRect` method (if needed) and call it's `reloadData`.

The `UIViewController` must override the delegate and dataSource methods for the outer table and the cell must override the methods for the inner table.

Also, make sure, the time the cells are plotted, your data is not `nil` or `null`.

And a very important fact, that people miss is the following code:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    }
```

Just dequeueing the cell is not enough. The first time a cell is dequeued, it is `nil` because it has not been created yet. Hence the `if` condition. Once it is allocated and initialized and added to the table, the dequeue code works thereafter.

**NOTE** : After looking more closely to your code (sorry for not looking the first time), I noticed you have allocated a `UITableViewController` to your cell. How do you think the cell is going to display a controller? Use a `UITableView` instead. Try to follow the pattern I have mentioned in paragraph 3. Use a table in the custom cell as a private member (or property, your wish), allocate it in `init`. Assign the data to the cell from your view controller. Then use this data to set the inner table view cell's properties in it's `drawRect`. It should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` does not create a cell if none was found for dequeueing.

Create a cell manually, or use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`

Comment: How do I create a cell manually?  If I use initWithStyle I can't see anything in my tableview.

Comment: It doesn't have any code, except for a @property for the field property.  It's a prototype cell inside the child UITableView.

Comment: I doubt that such a setup is supported through storyboards.

Comment: OK. Thanks for your help.  Since the "child" works fine on its own, I'm going to assume it's not possible to nest two UITableViews with custom cells.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes - @vikingosegundo is correct, but to expand his answer, you need to also register your cell first.  `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` may return nil. And if it is you need to create your cell,s but `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: forIndexPath:` will always return a valid cell, the catch is you need to tell it what kind of cell, that is what `registerClass` does.

Do this for both UITableViews.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tableView registerClass:[ContactFieldCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ContactFieldCell"];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *thisCellIdentifier = @"ContactFieldCell";

    ContactFieldCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:thisCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.delegate = self;
    cell.field = [self.card.sortedFields objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Adding the registerClass line returns a ContactFieldCell, but none of the labels are connected anymore (i.e. cell.displayNameLabel return nils).  It's worth saying that if I call this code without the parent UITableView I don't have any problem.  Thanks for your help ansible.

Comment: Where is displayNameLabel created?  Where is it declared? Your code for your cell only has two properties, delegate and field.

Comment: It's declared in the .h file and connected in the storyboard.

Comment: That's odd - I don't see it in the code you posted - `@interface ContactFieldCell : UITableViewCell`.

Comment: I removed it because I didn't think it was relevant.  There's 10 properties in there, all linked in the storyboard to their relevant views.  I don't think it makes a difference though, does it?

Comment: Well, you said setting the background color worked, which confirmed the cells are created and being shown.  But you also said the labels were returning nil.  So it seemed like a valid question for me. The last suggestion I have is try manually setting the text `cell.displayNameLabel.text = @"TestText"`. But if the label is really nil, nothing should happen. It would point to a problem with IB. I don't use it so I'm not sure I'll be able to help much.