# UITableView inside UITableViewCell in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Is it possible to create an UITableView inside UITableViewCell?

I want to create layout like this. In that i have Taken one MainUItableView and other is the SubUITableView. MainUItableView consists of SubUITableView. For example Classification is part of SubUITableView which is kept in MainUITableView.

You can find out the layout image which from this url : http://filedb.experts-exchange.com/incoming/2014/08_w35/869555/IMG-1101.jpg

Comment: a UITableViewCell is a UIView, which means you can put another UIView inside but that is asking for troubles ;) Why do you want to do that ? And have you consider UICollectionView ?

Comment: Refer this link :- http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/06/29/adding-a-uitableview-inside-a-uitableviewcell/

Comment: @teriiehina Please find the images from the url mentioned above or else click on this link : http://filedb.experts-exchange.com/incoming/2014/08_w35/869555/IMG-1101.jpg

Comment: @Amit : I have gone to this link before. But i could not found any help from it. If you have other reference then please provide that also.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21365167/nested-uitableview-not-returning-any-cells/21366827#21366827) answer of mine might help you. Nesting table views is acceptable.

Comment: Also try this link :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398058/is-it-possible-to-add-uitableview-within-a-uitableviewcell